# Numpy Efficient Rolling Intervals Statistics

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a huge numpy array ~200Million Rows loaded into memory.

I have a `int` timestamp column and I want to perform multiple queries the large array and calculate some statistics for intervals of 30minutes. Current I am using `np.where((arr[:,0] > ts - 1800) & (arr[:,0] < ts + 1800))` for each query, however it is rather slow.

Is there any way to perform these queries faster or possibly in bulk? Is it possible to utilize sorting/indexing the numpy array based on the column I want to query on?

Comment: If you are making enough queries based on the same column, it should be worth it sorting by that column: What you are gaining is 1) you can use searchsorted to find the interval boundaries which is O(log n) instead of O(n) for where (for rolling interval you can even get O(1)) 2) you can address the interval as a slice, meaning it will be a view, while the where based selection will make a copy.

Comment: Is the data is regularly spaced so that you have the same amount of rows for every 30 minutes? Reshaping might be helpful in that case.